# How to change the distance between X-axis scale texts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to increase the spacing of the texts in the x-axis scale, does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

[image]

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = cases, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey") +
  labs(x = "cases", y = "Trace Count") +
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Increase the size of the window that's showing the graphic. Otherwise, since you're plotting a categorical variable on the x-axis, you either get all of them (like this) or you can subset them (in case it's _ordinal_, and one can infer what is between two values).

Comment: You can make the text smaller, make the plot wider, show a subset of labels (if there's some way to imply the others), or show the data in facets to only show a portion at a time. Logically speaking, is there any other alternative?

Comment: Useful tutorial on ggplot2 resolution: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/.   You might also look at the `camcorder` package for WYSIWYG while twiddling your plot size settings.

Comment: This might also be a good use case for an"UpSet" plot: https://github.com/const-ae/ggupset

Comment: Thank you! Making the text smaller seems to be one way. But making the plot wider doesnt change the text of the x-axis. I just wonder if there is a way to really increase the distance of the text in the x-axis and the distance between bars at the same time.

Comment: With a given plot width in pixels, to get more space between the text and bars necessarily requires you make the text smaller and bars narrower, since total_pixel_width = pixel_width_of_elements + pixel_width_between_elements.  So you could use `width = 0.8` or some other number to make the bars narrower.